# Grouping raw datasets in a kedro visualization

Tags: namespaces, pipeline, kedro

I am looking for a way to group all of the raw datasets in a kedro pipeline visualization into one collapsible/expandable "node", similar to the way that namespaces are collapsible/expandable. In order to do this with a namespace, however, it seems that you need a function with inputs and outputs, which obviously would not be applicable at the raw data stage.

Here is my current visualization:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQBO8.png)

I would like datasets 0-5 to be grouped together into an expandable "node" called "raw data".

I have searched stackoverflow, the kedro docs, and the community forum on github for ways to accomplish this, without finding much that is relevant. The closest concept I found is namespaces, but again it seems these need a function, input, and output.

Answer (score 0):

So the start and the end of namespaced visualisation will not be collapsed, it's not something that's configurable